# Ruby on rails File Upload and download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here I want to fulfil the function which is to upload file  and then download in ruby on rails.

First I add function in Application Controller

```
def uploadFile(file)
if !file.original_filename.empty
  @filename = getFileName(file.original_filename)
  File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/files/#{@filename}", "wb") do |f|
    f.write(file.read)
  end
  return @filename
end
end

def getFileName(filename)
if !filename.nil
  return filename
end
end

def save(file, description)
@filename=getFileName(file.original_filename)
@filesize=getFileName(file.length)
@uploadfile = Uploadfile.new
@uploadfile.filename=@filename
@uploadfile.filesize=@filesize/1024
@uploadfile.description=description
@uploadfile.save
end
```

Second, I add upload in my controller which is for file upload.

```
def upload
@uploadfile = Uploadfile.new
unless request.get
  i=params[:file].size
  for num in(0..i-1)
  if filename=uploadFile(params[:file][num])
    savefiles(params[:file][num],params[:uploadfile][num])
  end
end
end
end
```

Finally, I add html in my new.html.erb which is the page I am gonna to upload file and submit.

```
  <%=form_tag ({:action=>"upload"}), :multipart=>true %>
  <divid="MyFile">
  <inputid="file"name="file[]"size="30"type="file"/></br>
  <inputtype="text"id="uploadfile_description"name="uploadfile[]"></br>
</div>
<inputtype="button"value="add"onclick="addText()"/>
<inputstyle="cursor:pointer"type="submit"value="upload"/>
<%=form_tag%>
```

Eventually, I still got mistakes on this.

No route matches {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"cplectures"}

How am I going to fix it without paperclip or other gems, and after that how to download this file from the front side with a download button.
Thanks guys

Comment: Can you include your routes.rb file?

Comment: The route doesn't match because you shouldn't try to route to your application controller.  Create a new controller instead, e.g. `rails g controller documents upload download` This will create a controller, add routes and view folder and files for the actions, upload and download.  Put your code in that controller and try again.

Comment: you guys mean I need to create controllers for upload and download... BUT the file I upload is in my lecture controller and through lecture new.html.erb page

Comment: The convention in Ruby is to name methods with underscore-style names, so those methods should be called `upload_file`. Additionally the use of `get` in a name is strongly discouraged. I'm not sure what `getFileName` actually does, as it returns whatever it's given, that logic to test for `nil?` simply returns `nil` if it's `nil`. Remember that `return` is implied, so the last thing evaluated in each method is automatically returned.

Comment: show your routes `rake routes|grep cplectur`, or explicitly addd the route to `cplectures#upload` for the specific HTTP action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your form us sending `GET` where it should be a `POST` or vice-versa. First, check your routes by running:

```
rake -T
```

and find your controller, action combination there. Check the http verb expected, and send it with your form like this:

```
<%= form_tag "", method: :get %>
```

assuming your post is happening to the same route you're in.